# Exit from child, parent and grand parent function

Tags: jquery, function, exit

I have a page that lists the names and other details of a number of videos. A user, who has already logged-in can click on the name of this video, to add the particular video to his/her portfolio. Please note that this list of videos can be seen both by somebody who has logged in and someone who has not. So I have codes that do the following -

a) On clicking the video a function checks if the person is logged in. If not an error message is flashed. Otherwise the code proceeds with a call to a second function.

b) In the second function, a box appears, which asks the user to enter a password for verification (These are paid videos and hence this double check). Here comes the problem. The user can decide not to proceed entering his password and simply close the new box. He might have entered a wrong password or his account may get clocked for entering wrong password for more than a certain number of times.

The problem that I am facing is that if the user closes the password box, then clicks some other video, again closes the password box without entering the password, then clicks another video and enters the password correctly. What is happening is that all the three videos are getting added to that users portfolio. I hope I have made my problem clear. What I want to achieve is that on closing the password box, one should exit the the entire chain of functions. This is not happening and post closing the box, the function is simply hanging without exiting. Kindly help.

Here are my codes -
1) Code for clicking the video name

```
    $(document).on("click", "[id^='Concept']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var x = $(this).attr('id').substring(7);
    checklogin(x);

});
```

2) Function checklogin

```
 function checklogin(id){

$.ajax({
        url: "mysession.php",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.userid === ""){
                alert("Please login/register to create you portofilio of tutorial videos");
            }else{
                                   checkpass(id);
            }

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status+",  " + jqXHR.statusText+",  "+textStatus+",  "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

}

3) Function checkpass

```
function checkpass(id){
$("#pwdErrMsg").html("Please enter your Tutorial Password");
$("#Transaction").css("display","block");
var tutexit = false;
    $(".close").click(function(){
            $("#pwdErrMsg").html("Please enter your Tutorial Password");
            $("#transpwd").val("");
    $("#Transaction").css("display","none");
            tutexit = true;
            return false;

});
    if(tutexit)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $("#callpwd").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedData = $("#pwdform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Tutelogin.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
            data: serializedData,


        success: function(response){

            if(response.indexOf("invalid")>0){
                                $("#pwdErrMsg").html(response);
                                $("#transpwd").val("");
            }else if (response.indexOf("missing")>0){
                                $("#pwdErrMsg").html(response);
                            }else if (response.indexOf("locked")>0){
                                $("#pwdErrMsg").html(response);
                                $("#Transaction").css("display","none");
                                tutexit = true;
                                return false;
                            }else if (response.indexOf("Success")>0) {
                                addtutorial(id);
                                $("#Transaction").css("display","none");
                                tutexit = true;
                                return false;
                            }

        },
        error : function (ts) {
                              alert(ts.responseStatus);
                          }
    });
    });

   if(tutexit)
    {
        return false;
    } 

}
```

Function addtutorial finally adds the video to portfolio. I am not providing the function as that is not the problem.

Comment: when moving back and forth in a ui, or chaining functions with multiple entry points, a classic pb is that you bind dom event handlers multiple times. You should use event delegation (listen all your events on the body element). Not sure if that's the pb here though

Comment: Anything specific that I need to do?